# node-db-migrate, unable to execute multiple queries

Tags: mysql, migration

I am using node-db-migrate in my project to handle the database migrations. It works fine when I am using only one statement but if multiple statements are used, sometimes it runs while it fails most of the time.

Here is my `database.json`

```
{
    "dev": {
    "driver": "mysql",
    "host":"localhost",
    "user": "root",
    "database": "PMS",
    "password": "jay123!",
    "multipleStatements": true
  },

  "test": {
    "driver": "mysql",
    "user": "jay123!",
    "host":"localhost",
    "database": "PMS_test",
    "password": "jay123!",
    "multipleStatements": true
  },

  "prod": {
    "driver": "mysql",
    "user": "jay123!",
    "host":"localhost",
    "database": "PMS",
    "password": "jay123!",
    "multipleStatements": true
  },
  "sql-file" : true
}
```

My up file

```
CREATE TABLE `user_types` (
  `id` int(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_type_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My down file

```
DROP TABLE users;
DROP TABLE user_types;
```

The down file works fine. but whenever use up file I get the error as below:

```
Error: ER_TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR: Table 'user_types' already exists
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
at Parser.write (/var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
at Protocol.write (/var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:266:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:253:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:211:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:587:20)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
at Connection.query (/var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:208:25)
at /var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/db-migrate-mysql/index.js:371:29
at Promise._execute (/var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:180:9)
at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:462:18)
at new Promise (/var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
at Object.runSql (/var/www/html/PMS/node_modules/db-migrate-mysql/index.js:366:12)
at /var/www/html/PMS/migrations/20171013202756-users.js:32:15
at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-migrate/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)
```

To debug the same I called the same with `--dry-run` flag then I observed that the create queries are getting generated twice which might be the cause of error. Please help me how to sort it.

Dry run output

```
[INFO] dry run
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `migrations` (`id` INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, `name` VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, `run_on` DATETIME  NOT NULL) ;
SELECT * FROM `migrations` ORDER BY run_on DESC, name DESC;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;;
START TRANSACTION;;
received data: CREATE TABLE `user_types` (
  `id` int(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_type_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_types` (
  `id` int(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_type_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
;
INSERT INTO `migrations` (`name`, `run_on`) VALUES (?, ?) [ [ '/20171013202756-users', '2017-10-14 20:50:48' ] ]
[INFO] Processed migration 20171013202756-users
COMMIT;;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;;
START TRANSACTION;;
received data: CREATE TABLE `user_types` (
  `id` int(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_types` (
  `id` int(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
;
INSERT INTO `migrations` (`name`, `run_on`) VALUES (?, ?) [ [ '/20171013205017-user-types', '2017-10-14 20:50:48' ] ]
[INFO] Processed migration 20171013205017-user-types
COMMIT;;
[INFO] Done
```

While searching a bit I landed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302476/mysql-1050-error-table-already-exists-when-in-fact-it-does-not
and I thought that it might be a case of Schroedinger's table. I changed the database config and repeated the process but the result was same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with `node-db-migrate` plugin. I had written two migrations the second migration was conflicting with the first one. Once I removed the second migration file, everything worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

Abandon that tool!  It has multiple errors.

`START TRANSACTION` is closed (`COMMITTed`) implicitly by any DDL (`CREATE TABLE`, in your case.

Syntax error at `received data:`.

This shows up twice, causing the error you asked about:  `CREATE TABLE user_types` -- Is that your fault?  Or the tool's?

Don't use `CHAR(...)` for variable length fields; use `VARCHAR(...)`.

The `(14)` in `INT(14)` means nothing.  An `INT` is always 4 bytes and has a range of up to a few billion.